# Possible to create BigQuery Table/Schema without populating with Data?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a Table schema without first populating it with data? Preferably using Google's python client. Google's documentation does not seem to provide a clear yes or no answer. They suggest [creating a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#creatingatable) with a query, but this is both non-intuitive and again, not highly documented:

Comment: Please do some research and questions like is it possible ? how to do it ? what is the error in my code ?  are strongly taken down on SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In python you can run an insert job on the tables API endpoint and that will create an empty table as it's documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert) you need to supply a [TableResource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource)

```
project_id = <my project>
dataset_id = <my dataset>
table_id = 'table_001'
dataset_ref = {'datasetId': dataset_id,
               'projectId': project_id}
table_ref = {'tableId': table_id,
             'datasetId': dataset_id,
             'projectId': project_id}
schema_ref = {<schema comes here>}
table = {'tableReference': table_ref,
         'schema': schema_ref}
table = bigquery.tables().insert(
    body=table, **dataset_ref).execute(http)
```

**dataset_ref is a python trick to copy the contents to named arguments

Browse other [python + bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery+python) questions.

Comment: How is the {<schema comes here>} represted? Is it json like this: "schema": {
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "type": string,
        "mode": string,
        "fields": [
          (TableFieldSchema)
        ],
        "description": string
      }
    ]

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch05/tour.py#75 for an example of setting a schema.

Comment: The link is dead. Here is the updated one: https://github.com/j450h1/bigquery-e2e/blob/master/samples/ch05/tour.py

Comment: What is the value of "http" in the last line? If we omit it, none of this works for us - but it is unclear to what to set the http value.

Comment: it's the python connection stream